# How to audit Read Operations

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, audit-logging

> [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309664(v=crm.5).aspx) says: Audit of read operations is an **Unsupported Feature**.

Does it means that I can't audit read operations at all, or that I just can't do it with standart CRM tools and need to create a custom solution (plugin i.e.) for this case?

Comment: I need to log user's access to a specific entity records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means CRM doesn't provide a feature to audit read operations out of the box.

You can still build a custom solution to capture read information.

I have done this in the past by using a plugin that updates a 'Read By' field  (like the 'Created/Modified By') on the entity when a retrieve is performed on the record.

I then audit the 'Read By', so the read by information is also shown in the audit area.

Comment: Thank you for this idea. But in order to track access to every entity, I'll need to add this field to all these entities, this is kind of complicated.
So, I will do better, I create one custom entity called 'Access History', where I can store each request to my entities in very ordered manner. And then I just assign auditor to watch 'Access History' entity.